# CSS Images flexbox margin

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hello I am trying to use flex to evenly distribute the extra available width of the div box as margin between the images. I have tried using flex basis: 30%; however instead of evenly distributing margin to the images it instead stacks the images vertically on top of each other.

```css
.images-container{
 max-width: 1400px;
 margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
 display: flex;
 background: #595959;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
.images{
 /* flex-basis: 30%; <- Issue */
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="images-container">
  <div class="images">
   <img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300" alt="Maths">
   <img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300" alt="ComputerScience">
   <img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300" alt="Physics">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`justify-content: space-between` does exactly what you are trying to do. It doesn't work in your code, because you put another div around your images. If you remove the div "images", it works:

```css
.images-container{
 max-width: 1400px;
 margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
 display: flex;
 background: #595959;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
.images{

}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="images-container">
   <img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300" alt="Maths">
   <img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300" alt="ComputerScience">
   <img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300" alt="Physics">
 </div>
</body>
```

If you want to keep the extra div, you have to change your CSS so that the images div is your flex container:

```
.images-container{
        max-width: 1400px;
        margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
        background: #595959;
    }
    .images{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your flex-container `.images-container` has only ONE child element, which is the `.images` DIV.

If you want flex to influence the images themselves, you have to apply `display: flex` to `.images`, not to `.images-container`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
img {width: 30%;height: 30%;}
```